# How to add State/Province to dname variable using shell script when creating the client ssl certificate?

Tags: shell, ssl-certificate, sh, keytool

```
TZ=`date +%Z`
DNAME="${DNAME}S=${TZ}"
```

The above code gives `S=GMT` or any timezone.

How can I get something like `S=Asia/Kolkatta`?

Comment: Where would "Asia/Kolkatta" come from?

Comment: i don't get your question..

Comment: What is the source of the information "Asia/Kolkatta", do you mean it is "your current location" or what? I think the answer from mauro goes into the right direction?

Comment: it is the client location. i want to get the client state/province to generate ssl certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting GMT because you system Timezone is set to GMT.

If you want to get State/Province via `date` you have to change your system Timezone. Or, alternatevely, just set TZ to the timezone you like rather than using `date`. For example:

```
export TZ='Asia/Kalkatta'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually i want to get the client timezone. But when i try `echo $TZ` (without exporting TZ) i don't get any output.                            when i export `TZ`  as you said i get the output as expected .